# List ip addresses accessing remote machine through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel

Is there a log file or utility that will display a list of IP addresses and time-stamped that tried to access a server through ssh? This log file would reside on the server. I came across this post https://serverfault.com/questions/88452/how-to-know-who-is-accessing-my-system but this is on Windows OS. Looking for an equivalent for Linux or in specific RHEL.

Looking forward to your feedback and suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a file called

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

OR

```
/var/log/secure
```

this log should contain all logins (failed and succeeded)